# IPv6 accessibility and Hitron Router

Tags: networking, router, ipv6, modem, isp

For my Hitron CODA-4582U Router, this is the best I can find and come up with -

[image]

However, trying to connect from internet failed:

```
Immediate connect fail for 2607:9880:3627:ffa4:92b1:xx:xx:681f: Network is unreachable
```

What would be the problem? Could it be --

- The Hitron Router configuration looks so different from [Website accessible via IPv6 is not accessible from outside of my network](https://superuser.com/questions/1581192/) that I don't know if I've configured it correct or not.
- Moreover, my machine is behind my ISP's NAT, i.e., it doesn't have a direct public IPv4 connection.

Or something else?

Or, maybe testing from Azure is not OK? I cannot even get to google via IPv6 testing from Azure:

```
$ curl -v6 https://google.com
* Rebuilt URL to: https://google.com/
*   Trying 2607:f8b0:4004:804::200e...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Immediate connect fail for 2607:f8b0:4004:804::200e: Network is unreachable
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Couldn't connect to server
```

So maybe my IPv6 is in fact working? How can I test its connectivity?
Pls help.

Comment: I found [this port scanner](http://www.ipv6scanner.com/). It reports correct information for my connection. Maybe try with that instead of your Azure VM with broken IPv6. :-)

Comment: Thanks @DanielB, that's the answer! All went well with my setting via the port scanner you suggested. I can accept that as the answer. Azure VM deceived me.

Comment: Hmm, _"You can specify a host name, IPv4 or IPv6 address."_ Both of my IPv4 or IPv6 address reported as "open" by it, but even me cannot get to my IPv4 address -- This site can’t be reached. So I'm not sure now...

Comment: Who knows what your ISP is doing if you have DS Lite.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cannot even connect to Google, it appears IPv6 is not correctly set up on your Azure VM or Azure may have intermittent network trouble.

I found [ipv6scanner.com](http://www.ipv6scanner.com/) which lists correct information for me, for both IPv4 and IPv6 (I have full dual stack connectivity).

Your router configuration looks correct. So unless your ISP is blocking all incoming unsolicited traffic, it should work.